# Google JSAPI Breaking Requirejs

Tags: javascript, google-api, requirejs, google-visualization

I shall start by creating a list of the order my scripts are loaded in:

```
<script src="/shared/js/requirejs/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After that I have a file that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["bar","line"]}); <--- this breaks everything

  require(['jquery','moment','underscore','validate','serializeObject','datepicker'],function($,moment,_){
    // Do stuff in here
  });
</script>
```

**Does anyone have any clue as to why google.load(); causes my page to break?**

1. Sometimes it throws "Object doesn't support property or method 'extend' (require.js)"?
2. Sometimes it acts like validate or underscore has not been loaded when it gets to parts of my code that use them.
3. Other times, the page loads just fine and works.